# verificar se dados existem no banco de dados

Tags: php

estou aprendendo php orientado a objetos e queria saber como coloco `if` para verificar se dados já existem no banco de dados

```
<?php

  include "head.php";
  if(isset($_POST['email'])){

     include 'class/classEmpresa.php';
     $empresa = new empresa();
     $verificacnpj = $empresa->verificaCnpjExiste($_POST['cnpj'],$conectaBanco);
     $id_empresa = $empresa->cadastraEmpresa($_POST['nome_fantasia'],$_POST['cnpj'],$_POST['telefone'],$_POST['email'],$conectaBanco);

     include 'class/classPessoa.php';
     $pessoa = new pessoa();
     $verificacpf = $pessoa->verificaCpfExiste($_POST['cpf'],$conectaBanco);
     $id_pessoa = $pessoa ->cadastraPessoa($_POST['nome'],$_POST['cpf'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['telefone'],$id_empresa,$conectaBanco);

     include 'class/classUsuario.php';
     $usuario = new usuario();
     $verificaEmail = $usuario->verificaEmailExiste($_POST['email'],$conectaBanco);
     $cadastraUsuario = $usuario ->cadastraUsuario($_POST['email'],$_POST['senha'],$id_pessoa,$conectaBanco);     

     include 'class/classHtml.php';
     $msg = new html();
     $mostrar = $msg->mostrarScript('cadastrado com sucesso!');
     echo ($mostrar);
   }
?>
```

Comment: Precisa tomar cuidado com essas verificações de "se existe". Se for para inserir novo registro, a maneira correta é tentar inserir e falhar caso já haja, para evitar race condition. Um erro que eu vejo em quase todos os """sistemas caseiros""" em PHP (e em algumas outras linguagens, com menos frequencia) é a pessoa fazer o teste separado da inserção, o que permite que dois registros sejam inseridos caso ocorram "quase ao mesmo tempo".

Answer (score 4):

Você deve fazer um `SELECT COUNT(*)` no banco para verificar qunatos usuários possuem aquele campo, por exemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pessoa WHERE cpf = $cpf;
```

Isso irá retornar quantas pessoas possuem o cpf especificado.

No caso acredito que está fazendo isso através de funções em sua classe modelo seria algo assim (no padrão [STMT](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-stmt.php)):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

function verificarCPF($cpf) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pessoa WHERE cpf = ?;");
    $stmt->bindParam("s", $cpf);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    return $result->fetch_array()[0];
}
```

Depois basta fazer a verificação:

```
if(verificarCPF('000.000.000-00') == 0) {
    //...
}
```